# php update record based on fetch

Tags: php

[UPDATE: found solution. see my own answer, below]
i'm trying to learn php and i can't figure how to do something that seems extremely basic, i.e. update a record based on fetching criteria. here's the part of my code that successfully fetches the record:

```
mysql_select_db('top_choice_system');

$query = "SELECT item_name FROM main ORDER BY cw DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "-- item name --" . $row['item_name'];
```

how do i update the specifically fetched item?

ftr below is the code i successfully use to update a record. however, in the code below, i specify the record myself in the WHERE portion:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE main
    SET column5=28
    WHERE ITEM=15';
```

my point is i can't figure how to make the WHERE match the fetched record. (or, better yet, how to fetch AND update with the simplest, shortest method.) thank you in advance for any help.

rephrasing my question: i'm learning several things from online tutorials, but for some reason i can't find the most basic info about updating a record but NOT based the record's id: for example, you want to update the specific record that matches a specific criteria. (as in the example above, wanting to update whichever record will be at the top of a specific column if that specific column is ordered from top to bottom.)

Comment: In databases you usually have a primary key identifying each row. This is the one thing to pass to the update statement in the where part.

Comment: thank you Andre'. unfortunately, while i do know how to update a record based on the primary key, i can't figure out how to update a record based on a specific criterion instead. specifically, i don't know how to "update whichever record is on top when a specific column is ordered"

Comment: Working on the "record on top" will be at random, in most cases it will work, but when another record is inserted "on top", you will update the wrong data row. There is no reliable way to update a record without using it's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
update main set column5 = 
(SELECT item_name FROM main ORDER BY CW DESC)
```

you can use query like this update and select together your question is not cleared what data you want and which data you want to update so you can search about update select query and make your query as per your requirement....

Comment: thanks so much Sagar, but even though i made several attempts based on your kind suggestion, i'm still failing. there is one element i'm missing, i think. let's say i want to UPDATE the value in column5 to 25 for the item in question. my question is where in the syntax do i write "25"? (i.e. where in the code you suggest would i write the value with which i want to update the record?) - to be more specific, i want to update to 25 the value in column5 for whichever item is on top of that column if the column is ordered from top to bottom. thanks again.

Comment: alas, i don't know what "static" means. at any rate it's about updating a field that's set as an INT or even TINYINT. the field contains a number (an integer) and it's in column5. this is the situation: i want the php code to update the integer in column5 ONLY for the record that turns out on top when the table is ordered (desc limit 1) by column2. i can't figure out the code. what you suggested seems on track, but part of the problem is where in the syntax i would wirte the new integer that needs to go in that field in column 5...

Answer (score 0):

EUREKA:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE main
    SET testfield="YES" ORDER BY columnX DESC LIMIT 1';
```

note:the ORDER BY condition did not work with a WHERE line. it worked when i added it to the SET line.
(ftr found code on http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/update-statement/)